# mariadb Regexp sometime return empty in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, stored-procedures, mariadb

need help, i got trouble for few day.

the problem is regexp from subquery run on stored procedure, sometime return empty sometime correct.

```
    REGEXP
        (
            select group_concat(_data_grupkasbank_auth.datahirarki separator '|') from _data_grupkasbank_auth where _data_grupkasbank_auth.uid='1'
        )
```

if i replace subquery with string value, its always correct :

```
REGEXP
    (
        '/Sangatta/K3PC/|/Yayasan Balikpapan/Masjid/'
    )
```

here my dbfiddle run work perfectly, but not on direct myserver windows 10, mariadb 10.3.23

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pRWvdP3KUwv7rbTN7H7PZC/0

capture :
[result test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyVis.png)

[subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl3pv.png)

[direct string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO4WI.png)

(from Comment)

```
select  group_concat(_data_grupkasbank_view.kode_grupkasbank separator ',' )
    from  _data_grupkasbank_view
    where  _data_grupkasbank_view.hirarki_grupkasbank REGEXP 
      ( SELECT  group_concat(_data_grupkasbank_auth.datahirarki separator '|')
            from  _data_grupkasbank_auth
            where  _data_grupkasbank_auth.uid='1' 
      )
    INTO  v_tempsql
```

Comment: Can't you simply do a `GROUP_CONCAT()` instead of that cursor loop??

Comment: the point is not cursor loop but regexp result,
i try remove cursor and use group_concat() suggested but still same result, sometime blank sometime correct, here query :
    select 
    group_concat(_data_grupkasbank_view.kode_grupkasbank separator ',')
    from
    _data_grupkasbank_view
    where
    _data_grupkasbank_view.hirarki_grupkasbank
    REGEXP
    (
     select group_concat(_data_grupkasbank_auth.datahirarki separator '|') from _data_grupkasbank_auth where _data_grupkasbank_auth.uid='1'
    )
    INTO v_tempsql;

Comment: Give `FIND_IN_SET()` a try.

Comment: Same here. Any news, @Irwanto??

Comment: i use 2 temporary variable, this work,


DECLARE v_temp1 TEXT;
DECLARE v_temp2 TEXT;

select
group_concat(yourfield separator '|')
INTO
v_temp1
from
table;
   
SET v_temp2 = v_temp1;

select 
field1, field2
from table
where
field1 regexp v_temp2;

Answer (score 0):

i dont know, but this work, i use this to assign SET v_temp2=v_temp1;

```
    -- //////////        
    
    DECLARE v_temp1 TEXT;
    DECLARE v_temp2 TEXT;
    
    select
    group_concat(yourfield separator '|')
    INTO
    v_temp1
    from
    table;
    
    SET v_temp2 = v_temp1;
    
    select 
    field1, field2
    from table
    where
    field1 regexp v_temp2;
    
    -- ///////////
```