# regexp receiving SELECT as param only works alternately (only odd times)

Tags: mariadb

Can anyone explain why this procedure has this behavior (only works on the 1st, 3rd, 5th... times)?

```
MariaDB [mydatabase]> CALL StrangerThings();
+-----------------+
| address         |
+-----------------+
| Prefix          |
| Prefix > Suffix |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mydatabase]> CALL StrangerThings();
Empty set (0.000 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [mydatabase]> CALL StrangerThings();
+-----------------+
| address         |
+-----------------+
| Prefix          |
| Prefix > Suffix |
+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [mydatabase]> CALL StrangerThings();
Empty set (0.000 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [mydatabase]> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                            |
+---------+------+------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1139 | Regex error 'NULL argument passed' |
| Warning | 1139 | Regex error 'NULL argument passed' |
| Warning | 1139 | Regex error 'NULL argument passed' |
+---------+------+------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `StrangerThings`()
BEGIN

    SELECT p1.address
    FROM (
        SELECT 'Prefix' as 'address' UNION 
        SELECT 'Prefix > Suffix'  as 'address' UNION 
        SELECT 'Another Prefix > Suffix > Last'  as 'address'
    ) p1
    WHERE
--      p1.address regexp ('^Prefix');
        p1.address regexp (SELECT ('^Prefix'));

END
```

If I replace this line
`p1.address regexp (SELECT ('^Prefix'));`
for this one
`p1.address regexp ('^Prefix');`
it works fine, prints the same expected result every time.

Important notes:

- It works as expected using Percona XtraDB Cluster (but I need it to run on a MariaDB)
- RLIKE function prints the same result as regexp
- 10.5.5-MariaDB-log runnning on CentOS 7
- I saw this related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62715945/mariadb-regexp-sometime-return-empty-in-stored-procedure) but since it has no answers I tried to put more info creating a new question

Comment: You get warnings when no results are shown. Pls share the exact warnings with us (show warnings).

Comment: I edited the question with the warnings. Thank you

Comment: Please file a bug with mariadb.com .  It fails for me on 10.3.21 but not on 8.0.16.  I got `Warning | 1139 | Got error 'pcre_exec: null argument passed' from regexp`

Comment: I did that.. Waiting now